# Querying Microsoft Server 2008 in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2008, dbi, unixodbc

I am currently using rails 2.3.8 and dbi gem to access mssql database. The production is located in turnkey rails VA and dev is located in linux VM
I am trying to figure out what previous developer had done to access the database server to no avail and all of the 'helpful sites have given me all kinds of errors' I cannot consider changing to tinytds as it breaks and would like to use the old approach. 
I currently have the following code setup to access and query mssql

ExternalData.rb

```
def self.datapoint_connection(&block)
   db_connection('type1',&block)
end

def self.db_connection(connection_type, &block)
  begin
    conn_data = YAML::load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/eg_databases.yml")[connection_type.to_s]
    driver = conn_data.delete('driver')
    user = conn_data.delete('username')
    password = conn_data.delete('password')
    conn_params = conn_data['entry']
    conn_str = "DBI:#{driver}:#{conn_params}"
    conn = DBI.connect(conn_str, user, password)
    if block_given?
      yield conn
    else
      return conn
    end
  ensure
      # disconnect from server
      conn.disconnect if conn && conn.connected? && block_given?
  end
end
```

eg_database.yml

```
type1:
  driver: ODBC
  entry: dsn_con1
  username: blah
  password: 'blah'
```

Query another database

```
def excluded_testrun_users
  ExternalData.datapoint_connection do |dbh|
    dbh.select_all("SELECT username FROM team where team") do |row|
      puts row
    end
  end
end
```

Overall query

```
def user_test_run_sql(granularity,date,end_date_condition=false)
  "(select * from test_run where user_id NOT IN 
  (#{excluded_testrun_users.map{|u| DataPoint.sanitize(u)}.join(", ")}) 
   #{' and testrun_end IS NOT NULL' if end_date_condition}) as sub_test_run"
end
```

I am wondering if this the the right approach to access multiple databases under the same server in mssql. Would dsn have to change(created) for every database connection but under the same server?

When I do try to run. I get the following error

```
Error getting query: Unable to load driver 'ODBC' (underlying error: uninitialized constant DBI::DBD::ODBC)

.... not gonna show stupidly long called path list to every conceivable files for ruby...
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
```

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'

```
script/server:3
```

Any insight or help would be much appreciated

Comment: "Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See here for a full explanation"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the dbi and dbd-odbc gems installed correctly. Check to make sure odbc.so and odbc_utr8.so files exist and you can require 'odbc' in irb.

http://gordonotspanish.blogspot.com/2010/02/resolved-uninitialized-constant.html

Comment: so odbc is missing when you attempt to require it in irb? Can you locate the .so files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bundle to handle your dependencies.
Use this in your Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

group :db do
     gem 'ruby-odbc', :require => 'odbc'
    gem 'tiny_tds'
    gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 3.1.0'
end
```

and make sure you have the unixODBC and UnixODBC-devel packages installed.

I also have one example online at: https://github.com/fidalgo/ruby-mssql-example